# Exchange 2010 Management Console missing

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange, exchange-2010, console-server

I have installed the Exchange Management Console in Windows 10 Pro for manage a Exchange 2010 server. It connects to the server, even the Exchange Management Shell (Power Shell) connects without problem. But I'm stuck because the console tree shows only Microsoft Exchange -> Microsoft Exchange On-Premises (server.domain.com), but there are not any other nodes (Organization configuration, Server configuration, etc.)
I'm using a domain admin account, and also tried run the console 'as administrator' with the same result.
[Exchange Management Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfjMp.png)
[image]

Comment: did you install IIS? http://www.exchangedictionary.com/solutions/install-the-exchange-2010-management-tools-on-windows-10

Comment: Yep -  https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=2516236AC4CD5FA3!6505&authkey=!ACFpD37m-tsbnys&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

Comment: What happens when you click on 'Microsoft Exchange On-Premises (server.domain.com)', any errors? Is the workstation on the same domain?

Comment: The workstation is in the same domain and the same VLAN. When I click there, the console connect with the server ("Initializing..."). Finally shows the same 'dashpanel' like the local console in the server: number of databases, servers, etc. There are links, for example: 'Manage Databases', and 'Manage Servers' but won't do nothing. The console tree won't open any other sub-node under the server.

Comment: Try deleting the following file: c:\users\<user>\appdata\roaming\microsoft\mmc\Exchange Management Console

Comment: Also did you enable .net 3.5?

Comment: Tried delete the file: the same
.net 3.5 was enable (by default) like this https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=2516236AC4CD5FA3!6544&authkey=!AF_hZKAyngsYJ4U&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

Comment: @smwk look like EMC won't works on Win 10 (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232090(v=exchg.141).aspx)

Comment: It's not supported alright but I was able to get it working on a test system. Guess you were just unlucky.

Comment: You can add the answer and I will vote it, finally you took your time. Thank you

Comment: Thanks Hedmon, maybe someone else will find the answer helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Exchange 2010 Management Tools are only supported on [Windows 7 or Vista](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232090%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx). You may get lucky and have it work on Windows 10 but there is no support for this setup.

> You can install the Exchange 2010 management tools on the following Windows operating systems:

```
Windows 7

Windows Vista with Service Pack 2 (SP2)

Windows Server 2008 SP2

Windows Server 2008 R2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great workaround to get Exchange 2010 console working on Windows 7, 8 also Windows 10.

1. Install Exchange 2010 SP2 Management Tools (make sure to install all the requirements first).
2. Copy `Exchange Management Console.msc` from any working computer (commonly it is in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Bin`).
3. Create a few folder on your C: drive (Something like ExchangeConsole) and paste the copied file (`Exchange Management Console.msc` from any working computer).
4. Rename the `Exchange Management Console.msc` file to `admin.msc` (inside `C:\ExchangeConsole`).
5. Create a .bat file (inside `C:\ExchangeConsole`).
6. Edit the bat file and write the following:

   ```
   @echo off
   set __COMPAT_LAYER=RUNASINVOKER
   set COMPLUS_VERSION=v2.0.50727
   admin.msc
   ```
7. Run the bat file every time you want to open the Exchange Console.